# Creating a class template which can take a class made from itself as an argument

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, policy-based-design

Is there a way to create a class template which can take an instantiation of itself as a template argument?

I would like to be able to say something this in my code:

```
Operation<float> op1(0.3f);
Operation<float, Operation> op2(0.5f, op1);
```

I tried defining such a class template with a variadic template parameter to avoid ending up in an infinite loop (the template would have to define a template template parameter which takes a template parameter itself which also has to take a template parameter and so on...).

```
template<typename T, typename... OP>
class Operation{
    Operation(T pVal, OP... pOP);
    ...
};
```

`typename... OP` should be able to take an `Operation<T>` or even an `Operation<T, Operation<T>>`

Is this possible?

Context: I am trying to build policy based functors which can be combined to form arithmetic "chain reactions". One operation uses a `Function` policy class to determine what it should do and it will also take two Source objects as arguments. the source objects may either be `Function` policies or other `Operation`s as both of these define the function `T execute()`. the final goal is to perform these arithmetic operations at runtime upon command by calling these functors.

Comment: `Operation` is not a class, so it cannot be used for a template type argument. `Operation` is a template class so it can be used in place of a template template type parameter. `Operation<float>` is a class and can be used in place of a template type argument.

Comment: Are you trying to build repression templates?  If you are you might want to look into what [`boost::proto`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/proto.html) can do for you.

Comment: @NathanOliver looks like this is actually what I am trying to do, only more general and fleshed out. Thanks for the resource!

Comment: @NathanOliver I guess you meant "expression templates"?

Comment: @Rerito Yeah.  Fingers did not communicate well with brain there.

Comment: There's a C++ idiom based on something like that, but I'll be darned if I can remember what it's called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use:

```
template<typename T, typename... OP>
class Operation{
    // ...
};
```

but usage would be

```
Operation<float> op1(0.3f);
Operation<float, Operation<float>> op2(0.5f, op1);
```

Comment: Thank you. Kind of obvious now. I tried to pass the template as an argument while I should have passed the instantiated class.

Answer (score 1):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters

> A template argument for a template template parameter must be an id-expression which names a class template or a template alias.
>
> When the argument is a class template, only the primary template is considered when matching the parameter. The partial specializations, if any, are only considered when a specialization based on this template template parameter happens to be instantiated.

I hope this helps in your problem. Look for "Template template arguments".